# Unable to delete Azure recovery services vault

Tags: azure

I'm unable to delete recovery services vault which is created for testing Azure-to-Azure replication with private endpoints. I've deleted all the associated resources(VM, Storage Account, Private Endpoints, VNets, Replicated Items, Replication container & policy, Network mapping, ASR Automation Account), but still not able to delete the vault. Tried deleting vault from azure portal and azure powershell as well. Nothing worked. Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that there is still a backup task or server registered with the vault. This may not be removed when the resource is deleted, so you need to go into the vault and look at the resources in the vault and delete them from there.